# How to calculate a differential of an Integral squared?

Tags: derivatives, gateaux-derivative

could anyone help me calculating the derivative of this function:

$G:C[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto \left(\int_0^1 x(s)ds\right)^2$

I tried using the Gateaux Differential - working out

$\frac{1}{s}(G(u+sh)-G(u)$ to then go $s\mapsto 0$

but this leads nowhere. I have the feeling this needs some "trick" regarding the squared integral. Could I write this differently?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $G(x) = \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds \right)^2$ gives
$$
G(x+h\xi) = \left( \int_0^1 (x(s) + h\xi(s))\,ds \right)^2
= \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds + h \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right)^2
\\= \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds \right)^2 + 2h \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds \right)\left( \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right) + h^2 \left( \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right)^2
$$
so
$$
\frac{G(x+h\xi) - G(x)}{h} = 2 \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds \right)\left( \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right) + h \left( \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right)^2 
\\ \to 2 \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds \right)\left( \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right)
$$
as $h\to0.$

Thus,
$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{G(x+h\xi) - G(x)}{h}
= 2 \left( \int_0^1 x(s)\,ds \right)\left( \int_0^1 \xi(s)\,ds \right)
.
$$

Comment: I just found an error and arrived at the same solution! Thank you very much! :D